# Why doesn't InputStream work with HTTPS in Android?

Tags: java, android, api, http, inputstream

While I was changing from open weather api to dark sky api, I found a problem with the connection.

I simply want to get the JSON-response from that api and with the open weather map api, everything worked just well. Now I decided to use the dark sky api instead. I just adapted everything as always but it doesn't work.

Maybe it has a problem with https? (the dark sky api uses an https-URL where the open weather map api used an http-URL).

Anyway, I catch an IOException in

```
inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

Here is my class:

```
import com.nymvno.hiob.prototyp_v30.Utils.Utils;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class WeatherHttpClient {

public String getWeatherData(String place) {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    InputStream inputStream;

    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(Utils.BASE_URL + place)).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        //Read the response
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line + "\r\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();
        connection.disconnect();

        return stringBuffer.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: what is that exception?Could you please post log cat error?

Comment: There is no exception I debugged it and figured out, that it jumps from the called line to return null

Comment: If there is no exception, why does your question say that there is?

Answer (score -1):

You must have to varify your host name from your Application class

check my code

```
    public class MyApp extends Application{
@Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
handleSSLHandshake();
}

@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
    public static void handleSSLHandshake() {
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
                }


            }};

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession arg1) {
                    if(hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("your host name")){
                        return true;
                    }else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are exactly doing. Might the host name be my api key? Do I need this SSLHandshake-handler?

Comment: Please add Application class in your package and add as in menifest.xml . give me your api url so i suggest whats your hostname

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned, there is just a difference of http/https protocol. For URLS, having https protocols, you must use HttpsURLConnection API rather than HttpURLConnection. If you use HttpURLConnection API for https url exception will be thrown. For further details you may refer below link.

https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html